# Is there an online community to find travel partners (for mountains, sightseeing etc.)?

Tags: online-resources, sightseeing, mountains, trekking, travel-companions

Is there an online community to find travel partners for mountain trekking or sightseeing, or anything else?

I don't want to travel to foreign mountains alone, but I don't know where to search for company. There's a great community for accommodation (I mean **CouchSurfing**) so I think there should be something in "reverse" direction (searching not the place to stay but the people to go with).

Comment: If you want to visit the Alps, then I could really recommend hikr.org

Comment: If dating travelers is your thing, [MissTravel](https://www.misstravel.com/) might be for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this does not involve providing a service or product, but something that's very much open to personal taste, I would think it much harder to actually maintain a successful platform in comparison to, say, couchsurfing.

That said, these communities or services do exist, though I have no personal experience with them. Here are a few:

http://globetrooper.com/

https://www.triptrotting.com

http://www.myholidaypartner.com/

http://www.twme.com.au/

http://www.ajungo.com/ (though this one seems to be more about leveraging your existing network of friends)

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is [meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com).  Here in Vancouver, at least, there are several travel groups on it, and many of them schedule trips together.

You can also try the [Lonely Planet Thorntree](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/) forums, and see who else is travelling in the same area, or even put up a post there for people to join you.  It's fairly common to see that on there.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I can think of is posting in the local groups and events section on Couch Surfing. You can post your trek as an event and get others to join you or you can find events that others are hosting and join in. You don't have to host or be be hosted to participate.

Answer (score 1):

I second meetup.com as a viable source though the quality of what you find in each city varies a lot.

There is also [internations.org](http://internations.org) which is an expat organization which usually has groups in most major cities around the world. But you might need to become a paying member to access the activity groups.

And then there is a digital nomad group [nomadlist.com](http://nomadlist.com) which on the surface is a city comparison site, but if you sign up for a one-time cost, you can join the community on Slack which has subgroups for many cities.