# Travelling to Vietnam: how to find a local friend or travel companion?

Tags: travel-companions

I'm planning to travel to Vietnam (Hanoi).

I would like to make a local friend or travel companion there and vice versa.
I'm willing to be a true travel accompany back in our country.

Is there any website for this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this is what you're looking for but couchsurfing may be a starting point:

https://www.couchsurfing.com/

as they claim on their website:

> Couchsurfing is a global community of 14 million people in more than 200,000 cities who share their life, their world, their journey. Couchsurfing connects travelers with a global network of people willing to share in profound and meaningful ways, making travel a truly social experience.

Hope it can be useful for you!

Also look at this question. It may help:

[Is there an online community to find travel partners (for mountains, sightseeing etc.)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8754/is-there-an-online-community-to-find-travel-partners-for-mountains-sightseeing?rq=1)